# django how to access an already uploaded video

Tags: python, django

i have uploaded a video to django and it's all working fine ..
but i need to render that video in the view.. 
django cant access it
any idea how to make django template see my uploaded files

modles.py :

```
class VideoData(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='vids'  )
```

forms.py :

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file  = forms.FileField()
```

and in template.html:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="vids/name.mov"  type="video/mov" />
 </video>
```

it shows an empty video player.

am i doing anything wrong ?

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an instance of `VideoData` named `vid` is in the template's context, you should use:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="{{vid.file.url}}"  type="video/mov" />
 </video>
```

To add the `VideoData` instance to the template's context, your view should look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import VideoData

def show_video(request):
    vid = VideoData.objects.get(id=1) # replace with correct query
    return render_to_response("template.html", {"vid":vid})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your video is uploaded media_root/vid directory(just check it on file system to make sure).
so when you call it from template you should write your media template in front of your video image. (So your url could be /media/vids/name.mov)
I also noticed that you are writing hardcoded video name here use something like following instead

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{my_video_data.file}}"  type="video/mov" />
 </video>
```

in order to use MEDIA_URL here you have to run your context variable through context processors checkout django.shortcuts.render method.

Comment: tried this and the path given is "C:\Users\moayyad\Desktop\bookfairp\..\bookfairp\vids\1_1.webm"<br>where it should be "C:\Users\moayyad\Desktop\bookfairp\vids\1_1.webm"